# Where does pydobc for python look for odbc drivers?

Tags: python, sybase, sap-ase

I just recieved a new box and I have installed the sybase drivers. ( I can see the drivers in the odbc data source adminstrator), but whenever I run a sript I always get the driver not specified error.

My database connect line is the following, which worked on my previous PC.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('driver={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};NetworkAddress=servername,port;Db=brass;uid=****;pwd=****;')
```

pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Is there a way to validate that the pyodbc path is set correctly?